# Is it acceptable to use an archive source such as the Wayback Machine and archive.is?

Tags: discussion

Is it acceptable to use these type of sources when the information doesn't exist anywhere else or it has disappeared in an answer or question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the information is pertinent to the question and answer, then I don't have an objection to it being used.

If there are alternative, more recent sources then those should be used. If no preferred alternative exists or the archive is used in conjunction with more current resources, it should be fine.